# How to get the current swipe tabs selected index value in codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I am using codename one swipe tabs dynamically to prepare some radio button but  on  swiping of tabs getSelectedIndex () method is giving the previous tabs value(previous in the sense suppose I move my tabs from 0 to 1 so it's giving me 0) so how to get the current tab value at which my tab is because on basis of this selectedIndexTab value I want my radio button to get selected.

Here is my code

```
TableLayout t1=new TableLayout(1, 5);
radioTypeContainer=new Container(t1);
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
t.addTab("Tab2"+i, new SpanLabel("Some text directly in the tab"));
firstTab = new RadioButton[i];
plain = new RadioButton("");
plain.setName("rdb"+i);
rbt =new RadioButton();
rbt.setName("rbt"+i);
radioTypeContainer.add(rbt);
finalRadioList.add(rbt.getName());
finalRadioList.add(t.getTabUIID());
}
borderLayoutContainer.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,radioTypeContainer);
t.addSelectionListener((i1, i) -> {
Log.p("====***======="+t.getSelectedIndex());
});
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

newSelected in selectionchanged method gives the current position of tab as shown in below code.

```
 t.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void selectionChanged(int oldSelected, int newSelected) {

Log.p("====***======="+newSelected);
            }
        });
```